# Passing JVM Arguments to a Java application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm a relative newbie to AWS and Elastic Beanstalk.

I have a Java application which requires me to pass JVM arguments on the command line. I need to pass a jasypt password and heap size settings.

I've read the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html#java-se-options), which describes how to accomplish setting environment variables which I can read in Java using System.getEnv(MY_ENV_VAR) but I need to pass JVM arguments not environment variables to the application.

Despite much searching, I cannot find a way to accomplish this task unless I use .ebextensions. Is this the preferred route to go?

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the following link in the [Amazon Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-procfile.html)

Creating a Procfile apparently is the way to go.